How can I configure Istio to send a max of 100 rps to one destination and route all excess requests to another destination?
I have a virtual service in Istio where I need to distribute incoming traffic between two destinations based on specific requirements. Specifically, I need to send a maximum of 100 requests per second to one destination at any point of time, while directing all excess traffic to the other destination.
Here's what I have so far:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - my-service
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: destination1
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: destination2
      weight: 0

I also tried using rate-limiting other than weights, but seems it doesn't support sending excess requests to another destination
